# kubuntu 17.04 plasmashell displays wallpaper then crashes other applications work

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

I'm new to kubuntu and have been using it for the past couple of months without any (non-self-caused) issues...

OS is Ubuntu Linux 17.04
kernel is Linux 4.10.0-38-generic on x86_64

Yesterday evening I left work and left the laptop running; this morning I found
plasmashell has crashed--I observed a black screen, but mouse, other programs, multiple desktops, dolphin, etc--all worked fine.  Just no "menu" bar, no desktop wallpaper.
Rebooted, logged in, saw the wallpaper, then it crashed again.

Ran plasmashell from konsole; wallpaper shows briefly (as on boot), then goes away.  Here's the output

```
kpizzolatto@SES-L02:~$ plasmashell
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
Reusing existing ksycoca
Recreating ksycoca file ("/home/kpizzolatto/.cache/ksycoca5_en_mje4N4X9OuhHvbu8uq3wZl4cjRo=", version 303)
Still in the time dict (i.e. deleted files) ("apps")
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Parse error in  "/home/kpizzolatto/.config/menus/applications-merged/xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu" , line  1 , col  1 :  "unexpected end of file"
Menu "applications-kmenuedit.menu" not found.
Saving
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
No file found for ".xml" , even though update-mime-info said it would exist.
Either it was just removed, or the directory doesn't have executable permission... ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share/mime", "/usr/share/mime")
No file found for ".xml" , even though update-mime-info said it would exist.
Either it was just removed, or the directory doesn't have executable permission... ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share/mime", "/usr/share/mime")
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/Roger Dean/1680x1050 package/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/Roger Dean/1680x1050 package/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/Roger Dean/1680x1050 package/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/Roger Dean/1680x1050 package/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/Roger Dean/1680x1050 package/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/Roger Dean/1680x1050 package/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/regular/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/regular/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/regular/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/Roger Dean/Random Stuff/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/Roger Dean/Random Stuff/"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/home/kpizzolatto/SES/kjp/Wallpaper/Roger Dean/Random Stuff/"
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.digitalclock/contents/ui/main.qml:78:27: Unable to assign [undefined] to QStringList
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.digitalclock/contents/ui/main.qml:37: TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateTime' of undefined
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:99: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
Notifications service registered
libkcups: Create-Printer-Subscriptions last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
Plasma Shell startup completed
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/kpizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
libkcups: 2
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/bin/plasmashell from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 10767
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 8 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 21 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 9 and type 'Read', disabling...

[1]+  Stopped                 plasmashell
kpizzolatto@SES-L02:~$ Unable to start Dr. Konqi
Re-raising signal for core dump handling.

[1]+  Segmentation fault      (core dumped) plasmashell
```

I see some other folks have tried running kdeshell as root, creating a complete new user, so tried that...new user, log in--pretty much the same behaviour, but slightly different output (due to no personalization I guess)

```
sespizzolatto@SES-L02:~$ plasmashell
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
log_klipper: Failed to load history resource. Clipboard history cannot be read. :  History file does not exist
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
kf5.kcoreaddons.desktopparser: Could not locate service type file kservicetypes5/plasma-popupapplet.desktop, tried ("/home/sespizzolatto/.local/share", "/usr/share/usr/share/xsessions/plasma", "/usr/local/share", "/usr/share", "/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:99: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
Notifications service registered
libkcups: Create-Printer-Subscriptions last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
Plasma Shell startup completed
libkcups: 2
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/bin/plasmashell from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1001/kdeinit5__0
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 8436
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1001/kdeinit5__0
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 8 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 19 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 9 and type 'Read', disabling...

[1]+  Stopped                 plasmashell
sespizzolatto@SES-L02:~$ Unable to start Dr. Konqi
Re-raising signal for core dump handling.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

[1]+  Segmentation fault      (core dumped) plasmashell                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
sespizzolatto@SES-L02:~$
```

finally, I also see some folks trying it as root with success, but this doesn't make much difference either--the wallpaper shows up for a moment, then goes away, no menus, no "tray", etc.

Comment: After a little more searching, it looks like the culprit is cups.  
After killing cups 
sudo /etc/init.d/cups stop
Now plasmashell runs OK
Starting cups again causes plasmashell to crash...

but...???why??? Printers were fine yesterday and I could print stuff today even with plasmashell not running.  How to stop plasmashell from dying against cups?

using local cups server and don't know any reason why permissions might have changed.

# /etc/init.d$ sudo ./cups start
...
...
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2

Comment: OK, I guess it was a problem in the system tray:  Deleting the printer widget from the system tray in kde and things are happier now!  Thanks to ApolloLV at superuser https://superuser.com/questions/1025103/kde-5-plasma-keeps-crashing-and-not-starting-again-no-task-bar-no-right-clic

Comment: Thanks for posting. Having similar issue of `plasmashell` crashing/freezing, but always worked around by manually re-launching `plasmashell` from konsole

Answer (score 2):

Workaround, not fix.
Disable the printer icon in the system tray
Ref https://superuser.com/a/1221053

Still don't understand why it quit working, though.

Comment: Probably this bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=326289 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-workspace/+bug/1770044