# Graphics issue on Kubuntu, plasmashell failed to start

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I use Kubuntu. I noticed something weird. KDE Plasma that happened to install updates but when I started the system I got some black and white effects, missing menu items, etc.

I made [this YouTube video to show what I mean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRnAB4BzUIU).

Everything is working okay (effects of icons, maximize etc), but I don't have a Desktop, and I can't right click on desktop.

I tried

- reinstalling whole kde plasma (that includes kubuntu +kde plasma, I using this setup on recovery)
- tried to uninstall fully complete and checked the files is here or no.
- tried to modify the kscreen (a folder including the conf)

plasmashell failed to start. Error :

```
dragonpc@dragonpc-H110M-DS2:~$ plasmashell 
org.kde.plasmaquick: Applet preload policy set to 1
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/code/LayoutManager.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/LayoutManager.js")
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/code/FolderTools.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderTools.js")
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:294:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:294:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Application Launcher" with a weight of 92
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
trying to show an empty dialog
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Digital Clock" with a weight of 12
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.panel/contents/code/LayoutManager.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.panel/contents/ui/LayoutManager.js")
trying to show an empty dialog
Failed to find service for Unity Launcher "application://Skype.desktop"
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Audio Volume" with a weight of 0
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Clipboard" with a weight of 0
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Device Notifier" with a weight of 0
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "KDE Connect" with a weight of 0
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/code/uiproperties.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/uiproperties.js")
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Notifications" with a weight of 0
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Printers" with a weight of 0
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Updates" with a weight of 0
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.battery/contents/code/logic.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.battery/contents/ui/logic.js")
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Battery and Brightness" with a weight of 0
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.battery/contents/ui/CompactRepresentation.qml:53:39: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
networkmanager-qt: void NetworkManager::NetworkManagerPrivate::propertiesChanged(const QVariantMap&) Unhandled property "AllDevices"
networkmanager-qt: void NetworkManager::NetworkManagerPrivate::propertiesChanged(const QVariantMap&) Unhandled property "Capabilities"
networkmanager-qt: void NetworkManager::NetworkManagerPrivate::propertiesChanged(const QVariantMap&) Unhandled property "ConnectivityCheckAvailable"
networkmanager-qt: void NetworkManager::NetworkManagerPrivate::propertiesChanged(const QVariantMap&) Unhandled property "ConnectivityCheckEnabled"
networkmanager-qt: void NetworkManager::NetworkManagerPrivate::propertiesChanged(const QVariantMap&) Unhandled property "Devices"
networkmanager-qt: void NetworkManager::NetworkManagerPrivate::propertiesChanged(const QVariantMap&) Unhandled property "GlobalDnsConfiguration"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "LldpNeighbors"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "Real"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "LldpNeighbors"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "Real"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "LldpNeighbors"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "Real"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "LldpNeighbors"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "Real"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "LldpNeighbors"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "Real"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "LldpNeighbors"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "Real"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "LldpNeighbors"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "Real"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "LldpNeighbors"
networkmanager-qt: virtual void NetworkManager::DevicePrivate::propertyChanged(const QString&, const QVariant&) Unhandled property "Real"
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Networks" with a weight of 64
Warning: all files used by qml by the plasmoid should be in ui/. The file in the path "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.bluetooth/contents/code/logic.js" was expected at QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.bluetooth/contents/ui/logic.js")
org.kde.plasmaquick: New Applet  "Bluetooth" with a weight of 0
trying to show an empty dialog
org.kde.plasmaquick: Delayed preload of  "Application Launcher" after 0.508 seconds
KAStatsFavoritesModel::setFavorites is ignored
trying to show an empty dialog
org.kde.plasmaquick: Applet "Application Launcher" loaded after 78 msec
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:294:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:294:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:294:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:294:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
QSGSimpleMaterialShader does not implement 'uniform highp mat4 qt_Matrix;' in its vertex shader
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/bin/plasmashell from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 13544
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 8 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 17 and type 'Read', disabling...
QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 9 and type 'Read', disabling...

[1]+  Stopped                 plasmashell
```

Comment: looks quite similar: https://askubuntu.com/q/972598

Answer (score 0):

<sup>this is not an answer (yet), so I make it a community wiki.</sup>

a few things, which probably don't fix your problem, but should be noted:

- use `kstart plasmashell` instead of just `plasmashell` [1]
- stop all other plasmashell processes using `killall plasmashell` before starting it again [1]
- I can see the line `[1]+  Stopped                 plasmashell` at the end of your log. it means you've ”stopped“ (!) `plasmashell` (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) instead of `TERM`inating it. if you start `plasmashell` without `kstart`, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate it.

In short: when problems with the plasma shell occurr, try if restarting it [1] helps.

[1] see [Can I restart the KDE Plasma Desktop without logging out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out)